# How do I set locale to GWT DateBox

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT DateBox implementation:

```
DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getLongDateTimeFormat();
dateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(dateFormat));
```

I would like to set different locales for the date. For example
If Browser language is France the date should be:

> 2014 Mars 14

If Browser locale is English

> 2014 March 14

and so on.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getDateTimeFormatInfo().dateFormatLong());
```

Or you can do in this way:

```
    Map<String, DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo> formats = new HashMap<String, DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo>();

    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatDE = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_de();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatEN = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatFR = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_fr();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatES = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_es();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatZH = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_zh();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatRU = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_ru();

    formats.put("de", formatDE);
    formats.put("en", formatEN);
    formats.put("fr", formatFR);
    formats.put("es", formatES);
    formats.put("zh", formatZH);
    formats.put("ru", formatRU);

    String language = getLanguage();

    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo format = formats.get(language);
    DateTimeFormat dateFormat = null;
    if (format == null) {
        dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale()
                .getDateTimeFormatInfo().dateFormatLong());
    } else {
        dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(format.dateFormatFull());
    }

    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));

    DateBox dateBox = new DateBox();
    dateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(dateFormat));
    RootPanel.get().add(dateBox);
```

using JSNI

```
public static final native String getLanguage() /*-{
    return navigator.language;
}-*/;
```

Screenshot for `French(fr)` locale

[image]

---

In above code date is formatted as per locale but still month is displayed in English language for e.g. March is not replaced with Mars for France.

To solve this problem we have to define locale.

Read here about [setting locale language dynamically initially](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-web-toolkit/1274mxrhxt/setting-locale-language-dynamically-initially).

Seems like there are 5 ways to provide the locale:

- 1.) using a query param named "locale". To use this method you can let your
  web server send a redirect from app.example.com to
  app.example.com/?locale= after determining the locale on your web
  server if possible or you do the redirect from within your app, e.g. in
  your onModuleLoad() you use Window.Location.assign( + ). You can change the name of the query param by setting a
  different value to "locale.queryparam".
- 2.) using a cookie. To use this you have to define the cookie name by
  setting "locale.cookie" to any value as in I18N.gwt.xml no default cookie
  name is defined.
- 3.) using meta tags. As already described you can include a gwt:property
  meta tag in a dynamic host page.
- 4.) using the user agent information. To use this you have to activate it
  by setting "locale.useragent" to "Y" as its disabled by default in
  I18N.gwt.xml.
- 5.) create your own property provider and use JavaScript to fill the
  "locale" property value yourself. Here you are completely free how to
  obtain the value.

GWT's default search order is "query param, cookie, meta, useragent" but
cookie and useragent will be skipped if you don't configure/activate them.
You could also modify the search order by setting "locale.searchorder" in
your gwt.xml.

Now choose one solution ...

Comment: I thought this is what happens by default if you don't set any format.

Comment: Yes, it uses default locale.

Comment: LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale() returns every time  - "default". No metter if my browser language is German or France

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try in this way. Obviously you have inherited locales in your gwt.xml in this way `<extend-property name="locale" values="fr"/>`. Add this information in a map with language as string as many as you have locale defined for your application.

Comment: You can change the date format by `DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo.dateFormatLong()` , `DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo.dateFormatMedium()`, `DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo.dateFormatShort()` etc.. Even you can define the date patten...

Comment: Braj thank you very much for the help! I have tried with your way and it seems me wonderful approach BUT it hasn't worked again. In my gwt.xml I do not have property for locale only <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/> Should I put some additional inherities in my gwt file?

Comment: Yes you have to inherit `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>` in your get.xml file that is used for GWT internationalization feature.

Comment: Yes, I have this inherit, but when I execute:
 DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatFR = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_fr();
 dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(formatFR.dateFormatLong());
dateFormat.format(new Date())  - the NEw date is on English again :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49775/discussion-between-braj-and-user2739823)

Comment: Wonderful!! THANK you very much my friend! This saves me a lot of time! Thank you once again for your time that you have spend helping me to solve me problem!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "browser language" - you cannot reliably detect it. The solution is to use GWT's [internationalization](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html). You can define different locales for your project. Then a user can choose a language for your app, and you can display all UI elements, including dates, in a way that users expect. Many elements - dates, currencies, numbers - will be displayed "correctly" without any changes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add a piece of javascript in the HTML that detects the language of you browser and set a GWT property

```
 <script>  
    var search = location.search;  
      if(search.indexOf("locale") == -1){  
        var lang = navigator.language!=null ? navigator.language : navigator.browserLanguage;  
        var lang = lang.replace("-", "_");  
       document.write("<meta name='gwt:property' content='locale="+lang +"'>"); 
       }  
   </script>
```

In Java, you retrieve the browser local

```
String currentLocalString = LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName();
```

And use the patterns [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) to format the date.

Comment: Thank you, but I can retrieve the browser language. The problem is that I can not put this language to my DateBox Object.