# Setting locales in gwt.xml do not work

Tags: java, gwt

In my module xml file I have this:

```
 <module rename-to="UIGenerator">
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP" />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML" />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />
 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales" />
 <set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent"value="Y" />
 <extend-property name="locale" values="de" />
 <extend-property name="locale" values="fr" />
 <set-property name="locale" value="de, fr" />
 <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="de" />
 <entry-pointclass="mypackage.UIGeneratorEntryPoint" />
 </module>
```

But every time when I try to use locales it returns me default one which is English.

```
   LocaleInfo.getAvailableLocaleNames(); this return Array of String with only one value   - default
```

IF I set    It works but only for German without   others!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you have mentioned in gwt.xml?

Comment: Its working as expected here is my output `[default, de, de_AT, de_BE, de_CH, de_DE, de_LI, de_LU, fr, fr_BE, fr_CA, fr_CH, fr_FR, fr_LU, fr_MC, fr_SN]`

Comment: Any error are you getting while running application?

Comment: No I do not have errors, but the date that I would like to print is on default english language in I use above xml. Even that I pass locale as parameter in URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an error while running application because of invalid your gwt.xml.

```
[Fatal Error] :13:53: Element type "set-configuration-property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

put a space before `value` as shown below:

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent" value="Y" />
```

I have posted a answer in the same context.

Please have a look at [How do I set locale to GWT DateBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408685/how-do-i-set-locale-to-gwt-datebox?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Screenshot for `German(de)` locale:

[image]

Screenshot for `French(fr)` locale:

[image]

---

**Complete Code:**

Note: just change `com.gwt.test.client.GWTTestProject` it with you actual Entry Point clas in your gwt.xml file.

**gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='gwttestproject'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales" />

    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />

    <set-configuration-property name="locale.searchorder"
        value="cookie,queryparam" />
    <set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent"
        value="Y" />

    <extend-property name="locale" values="de" />
    <extend-property name="locale" values="fr" />
    <set-property name="locale" value="de, fr" />
    <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="de" />

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='com.gwt.test.client.GWTTestProject' />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

</module>
```

**Entry Point class**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.LocaleInfo;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_de;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_es;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_fr;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_ru;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.cldr.DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_zh;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox;

public class GWTTestProject implements EntryPoint {

public static final native String getLanguage() /*-{
    return navigator.language;
}-*/;

public void onModuleLoad() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(LocaleInfo.getAvailableLocaleNames()));

    loacleDate();
}

public void loacleDate() {
    Map<String, DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo> formats = new HashMap<String, DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo>();

    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatDE = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_de();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatEN = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_en();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatFR = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_fr();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatES = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_es();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatZH = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_zh();
    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatRU = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_ru();

    formats.put("de", formatDE);
    formats.put("en", formatEN);
    formats.put("fr", formatFR);
    formats.put("es", formatES);
    formats.put("zh", formatZH);
    formats.put("ru", formatRU);

    for (String key : formats.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " - " + formats.get(key).dateFormat());
    }

    String language = getLanguage();

    DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo format = formats.get(language);
    DateTimeFormat dateFormat = null;
    if (format == null) {
        dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale()
                .getDateTimeFormatInfo().dateFormatShort());
    } else {
        dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(format.dateFormatFull());
    }

    System.out.println("Date formatted:" + dateFormat.format(new Date()));

    DateBox dateBox = new DateBox();
    dateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(dateFormat));
    RootPanel.get().add(dateBox);
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="GWTTestProject.css">
<title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="gwttestproject/gwttestproject.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've seen your post yesterday. But It still doesn't work: 
Every time me date in GWT Box is on default language if I do not specified the language explicitly with set-property, but this work only for specified property

Comment: The screenshot is showing a German locale (de), not a French one.

Comment: Sorry, I have tested it with German as well as French. My mistake. Let me change it. Let me do it for you. Working on it. I will come back it still its not working as expected. I am not good in language. :)

Comment: Its working just you have pass `locale=fr` in URL as query string and Refresh the page. I have tested with `fr` and `de` locale. Should I share the complete code?

Comment: Could you please share the complete code and is my gwt.xml file is properly set?

Comment: Done, I have appended it in my answer. Please try it now. Let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: I am trying now. Just a minute, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
I do not have these tags in my app
<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

Am I need them?

Comment: I get this Object from MAP   DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo formatFR = new DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_fr();

and when I format the date with it it is the same situation: Its on default locale - ENglish.
HEre I determine format - DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo format = formats.get(getLanguage()); where getLanguage() return me the proper language but still not working.....

Comment: Have you tested it by passing `locale=fr` in URL as query string? What is language setting of your browser?

Comment: I change language setting to be French. I get locale correctly but still this DateTimeFormatInfoImpl_fr() do not format the Date of French Language

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49824/discussion-between-braj-and-user2739823)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the locale for your app - either in HTML, or through a URL parameter. For example, you can include this in your HTML:

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=de">
```

Also, remove these lines:

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent"value="Y" />
<set-property name="locale" value="de, fr" />
```

I am following the examples offered in [GWT guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html), and I never had a problem with locales.

Comment: IT is the same again. GWT Uses default language wich is English even that I have removed these two lines

Comment: Sorry my friend It is the same again. I see only default language in Locales

Comment: How are you using the locale? How are you printing this date?

Comment: dateBox.setFormat(new DateBox.DefaultFormat(dateFormat));

      dateBox.setValue(new Date());
Where dateBox is DateBox gwt Object

Comment: dateBox.setFormat(dateFormat);

Answer (score -1):

First keep in mind that i18n locale **do not work well** under `gwt: run-codeserver`, so you must tested after full compilation.

And there is no reason for this two lines, just eliminate them to make it work:

```
<set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent"value="Y" />
<set-property name="locale" value="de, fr" />
```