# How does client GWT determine default time-offset/time-zone and how to change it?

Tags: gwt, timezone

Based on what GWT at the client side knows about the time-zone? Is it somehow retrieved from user-agent (browser) which in turn has it from OS settings? I tried tinkering with my OS time-zone settings but did not any different.

Is there a way to set the default time-offset/time-zone to be different at the client side code? Reason for this is usage of `Date` api methods which apparently return results based on the defaul time-offset/zone settings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change settings on a user's computer or in a user's browser. That would be a huge security hole.

To display date in the desired time zone, create and pass a TimeZone object to the DateTimeFormat.format() method.

Comment: I use `TimeZone` for formatted output. I was just wondering how setting of the default time-offset works. This question is out of curiosity to better understand principles.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my post [Setting locales in gwt.xml do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429774/setting-locales-in-gwt-xml-do-not-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) where I have explained it with sample code.

Specially look at `gwt.xml` and where you can define `locale`.

Hint:

- create the `DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo` based on client (browser/navigator) language
- create the `DateTimeFormat` based on `DefaultDateTimeFormatInfo`