# Why Date is not Serializing in GWT 2.6?

Tags: java, gwt

GWT 2.6 is not serializing Java Date properly.When i Enter the Date 17.10.1983 it shows 16.10.1983 and if I enter 16.10.1983 it shows 15.10.1983.How can i solve it?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: birthday = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(BirthDateBox.getValue());

just using the DateTimeFormat.but the code is working perfectly on MAC OS and LINUX.
@Baz

Comment: Could it be a timezone issue somewhere between client, JVM and database?

Comment: i printed 'birthday' values on client and server side.on client side it prints correctly and on the server side it gives the wrong value. I think it is not serializing correctly.
When i debug it,it also works correctly.@salk31

Answer (score 1):

It may be the locale/timezone issue. You can solve it by passing value as long (time in milliseconds) or string (date as string). Just form the date object back at the server side.

My another post might help you [Setting locales in gwt.xml do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429774/setting-locales-in-gwt-xml-do-not-work/22429938#22429938)

---

How you can form the the date object back at server side based on client locale?

Sample code:

```
Locale locale = httpRequest.getLocale(); // Get the client browser locale
SimpleDateFormat formatter = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
                DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale);
```

Comment: Yes, it **probably** is a timezone issue. `java.util.Date` is serialized by sending its `getTime()`, but then the _local date_ being represented is different depending on the timezone you want to print it with. E.g. now is `1400858550770` for me and Fri 23rd, that same timestamp in Australia is Sat 24th.

Comment: Put simply: if you want a _local date_, then don't use `java.util.Date`, or convert it to a day-month-year structure (or formatted string) before sharing it with someone else, or share the timezone along with the timestamp. Or wait for GWT to support Java 8 and its `LocalDate` (or contribute it!)