# How can I display one type of formatting in GWT application?

Tags: java, gwt, localization

Is it possible to force a GWT app to use a specific locale formatting in other locales?

I've tried following both ways.

```
// 1
private final static DateTimeFormat timeFormat1 = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("h:mm aa");

// 2
private final static DateTimeFormat timeFormat2 = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.TIME_SHORT);

public static void convertToShortTimeFormat(Date d) {
    if (d != null) {
        GWT.log(timeFormat1.format(d));  // displays localized format "10:30 vorm" in German
        GWT.log(timeFormat2.format(d));  // displays "19:30" for example
    }
}
```

For example, in North America we use time formatting like 12:34 PM, but other countries AM/PM may become its countries language. Is there any way to always display 12-hour notation?

Comment: You set the locale yourself. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I mean I always want time formatting to be same, in this case north american style 12:34 AM(PM) in no matter what locales are selected.
For example in German, "12:34 AM" in English becomes like "12:34 vorm" in my GWT app but I want the formatting to be displayed AM/PM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own [format patterns](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) instead of relying on built-in formats. This way it will always display dates, for example, according to the pattern you chose and regardless of the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) class. The best way would be to create a static reference to the date formatter that you will use everywhere in your code. For example:

```
public static final DateTimeFormat DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

public static final DateTimeFormat TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("hh:mm a");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tired your suggestion, however it still shows localized pattern for me...

Comment: Put code in my question, please take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: @penginryo did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429774/setting-locales-in-gwt-xml-do-not-work