# GWT DefaultLocalizedNames use current locale

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I want to print country-names localized to currently active locale. Therefore I came up with that code. But it always prints out the English names. Is there a way to set a locale here somehow. I can use e.g. the `LocalizedNamesImpl_de` to show German names but than I have to switch programmatically between languages then,

```
DefaultLocalizedNames loc2 = new DefaultLocalizedNames();         
// LocalizedNames loc2 = new LocalizedNamesImpl_de();         

for (int i=0; i<loc2.getSortedRegionCodes().length; i++) {

             String code = loc2.getSortedRegionCodes()[i];
             System.out.println(loc2.getRegionName(code));                 
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

I have already shared a post in the same context. It might help you resolve this issue.

Please have a look at below posts:

- [How do I set locale to GWT DateBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408685/how-do-i-set-locale-to-gwt-datebox?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Setting locales in gwt.xml do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429774/setting-locales-in-gwt-xml-do-not-work/22429938#22429938)

---

Sample code:

```
// a map contains mapping for all LocalizedNamesImpl based on language
Map<String, LocalizedNamesImpl> formats = new HashMap<String, LocalizedNamesImpl>();

LocalizedNamesImpl formatDE = new LocalizedNamesImpl_de();
LocalizedNamesImpl formatEN = new LocalizedNamesImpl_en();
LocalizedNamesImpl formatFR = new LocalizedNamesImpl_fr();

formats.put("de", formatDE);
formats.put("de-DE", formatDE);
formats.put("en", formatEN);
formats.put("fr", formatFR);

// browser (client) language
String language = getLanguage();
System.out.println(language);

LocalizedNamesImpl format = formats.get(language);

if (format != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < format.getSortedRegionCodes().length; i++) {
        String code = format.getSortedRegionCodes()[i];
        System.out.println(format.getRegionName(code));
    }
}

public static final native String getLanguage() /*-{
    return navigator.language;
}-*/;
```